# Hidden character in EPR paradox

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, epr-experiment

I am a beginner in Quantum Mechanics so i am pretty new to the EPR paradox although i have heard about it a long time ago but finally studying in detail. And came across a doubt: Why the hidden characteristics in any particle as predicted by Einstein can not exist? If anyone can provide an  elaborated explanation !

Comment: As with all "paradoxes" it's a play on your own false expectations in how nature should behave. In this case it's about the classical separability of "distant" sub-systems of a quantum mechanical system. If you study quantum mechanics from a modern perspective and you learn to accept that the classical world is a consequence of the quantum world and not the other way round, then the paradox disappears. Most importantly, learn to see the world without thinking about particles, they are of no help when it comes to quantum phenomena.